# Lazy<T> and reflection-based initalization

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I have a series of classes which initialize themselves when created based on using reflection to read a custom attribute on each property/field.   The logic for all that is contained in an `Initialize()` method which they all call, which exists on the base class they inherit from.

I want to add usages of `Lazy<T>` to these classes, but I don't want to specify the function(s) in the constructor for each class, because they are "thin" constructors and the heavy lifting is in `Initialize()`.  Conversely, I want to keep type-safety and such so I can't just provide a string of the code to use to initialize the `Lazy<T>`.  The problem is that any usage which refers to the specific properties of the object can't be used in a static context.

Specifically, this is what I want my code to look like in an ideal world:

```
public class Data : Base
{
    public Data(int ID) { Initalize(ID); }

    [DataAttr("catId")] // This tells reflection how to initialize this field.
    private int categoryID;

    [LazyDataAttr((Data d) => new Category(d.categoryID))] // This would tell reflection how to create the Lazy<T> signature
    private Lazy<Category> _category;
    public Category Category { get { return _category.Value; } }
}
public abstract class Base
{
    protected void Initalize(int ID) 
    { 
        // Use reflection to look up `ID` and populate all the fields correctly.
        // This is where `categoryID` gets its initial value.
        // *** This is where _category should be assigned the correct function to use ***
    }
}
```

I would then access this the same way I would if `Category` were an automatic property (or an explicitly lazy loaded one with an `_category == null` check)

```
var data = new Data();
var cat = data.Category;
```

Is there *any* way I can pass the type information so that the compiler can check that `new category(d.categoryID)` is a valid function?  It doesn't have to be via an `Attribute`, but it needs to be something I can see via Reflection and plug in to anything that has a `Lazy<T>` signature.

---

As an alternative, I will accept a way to do

```
 private Lazy<Category> _category = (Data d) => new Category(d.categoryID);
```

This could either avoid reflection altogether, or use it to transform from this form to a form that `Lazy<T>` can handle.

Comment: Is the `Data` instance you're using there supposed to correspond to the current instance, or some other instance?

Comment: @Servy - The current instance.  Edited in an example.

Comment: @Servy - Does the new edit better convey what I'm looking for?

Comment: Why bother?  If you just define the `Lazy` instance in the child class instead of in an attribute it's a comparable amount of work, and it gives you compile time type safety, rather than a big mess of runtime checks that are both slower, harder to read/change, more error prone, etc.

Comment: For legacy reasons, there's 8 different constructors for this class, all of which call some form of `base.Initialize()` (which ends up at the same call eventually), and probably 6 different fields I'd want to `Lazy<>`. I *could* add all six to all eight, but I'm attempting to not repeat myself.

Comment: Have all of the constructors call a derived class's initialize method (which can itself call the base class's initialize method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a solution inspired by @Servy's suggestion to get this working.  The base class's `Initialize()` method now ends with:

```
protected void Initialize()
{
    // Rest of code...

    InitializeLazyVars();
    /* We need do nothing here because instantiating the class object already set up default values. */
    foreach (var fi in GetLazyFields())
    {
        if (fi.GetValue(this) == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException("No initialization found for Lazy<T> " + fi.Name + " in class " + this.GetType());
    }
}
```

`InitializeLazyVars()` is a virtual method that does nothing in the base class, but will need to be overridden in the child classes.  If someone introduces a new `Lazy<T>` and doesn't add it to that method, we'll generate an exception any time we try to initialize the class, which means we'll catch it quickly.  And there's only one place they need to be added, no matter how many constructors there are.

Comment: That's not the inverse of what I suggested.  For all intents and purposes, it's *exactly* what I suggested.  Overriding `Initialize` isn't really any different at all from having `Initialize` call another initialization method that will be overridden.

Comment: I misread what you said, then.  I thought you were saying `constructor -> child.Initialize() -> base.Initialize()`, which loses the arguments to the constructor (or requires lots of `child.Initialize()` variants), as opposed to `constructor -> base.Initialize() -> child.InitializeLocal()`, which appends to the current flow instead of inserting into it.

Comment: The constructor would just call `Initialize`, which, being a virtual method, is going to call the derived class's implementation of the method.  The derived class's implementation would, within it, have a call to `base.Initialize` to ensure that the initialization in the base class can happen as well.  The call could be before or after the derived class's initialization.

Comment: Regardless, glad you were able to get it working, and I imagine this solution will be much more manageable than what your original question seemed to be asking for.

Comment: @Servy - It's more like `constructor(ID) -> base.Initialize(ID) -> base.Initialize(DataRow)` and `constructor(DataRow) -> base.Initialize(DataRow)` now, so I'd need to override both variants if I were using overrides of the base `Initialize()`.  And I *definitely* agree about being more manageable.